# C# Multiple Inheritance

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

Currently im studying the C# with ASP.NET MVC 4 with **Code First Approach**. Im Visual Basic Developer, and Now i want to Start C#. And, now i came accross the situation where i've to manage Multiple Inheritance. But, it is not possible with Class i thought. So, how should i manage these classes i have :

```
//I have the Following Person Class which Hold Common Properties 
//and a Type of Person e.g : Student, Faculty, Administrative
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}


//This is my Student Class, which is Derived from Person
public class Student : Person
{
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public DateTime EnrollmentDate { get; set; }
    public string Remarks { get; set; }

    public bool Approved { get; set; }
    public DateTime ApprovedDate { get; set; }
    public int ApprovedUserId { get; set; }
}


//This is my Faculty Class, which is also Derived from Person
public class Faculty : Person
{
    public DateTime HiredDate { get; set; }

    public bool Approved { get; set; }
    public DateTime ApprovedDate { get; set; }
    public int ApprovedUserId { get; set; }
}
```

What I want to Make is Approved, ApprovedDate, and ApprovedUserId also common. I want to Specify those Properties like :

```
 public class Approve {
    public bool Approved { get; set; }
    public DateTime ApprovedDate { get; set; }
    public int ApprovedUserId { get; set; }
}
```

And, want to use like  :

```
public class Student : Person, Approve
{
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public DateTime EnrollmentDate { get; set; }
    public string Remarks { get; set; }
}
```

And, i cannot put those things inside **PERSON**. Because, i've to use this to another classes to, but those are not Person.

Then, how do i achieve this...

Please give me an Example for the Above Situation.

Please Help. And, Thank You so much in Advance.

Comment: In C#, you can inherit one class and implement multiple Interfaces and you must put class first.

Comment: Or use Approve as a property in Student class

Answer (score 25, accepted):

One possible solution would be to modify your hierarchy:

```
public class PersonWithApprove : Person { // TODO: replace with non disgusting name
    public bool Approved { get; set; }
    // etc...
}

public class Student : PersonWithApprove {
}

public class Faculty : PersonWithApprove {
}
```

Or you could create an interface:

```
public interface IApprove {
    bool Approved { get; set; }
    // etc
}

public class Student : Person, IApprove {
}
```

You might also leave the class `Approve` as such, and have classes with a property of that type:

```
public class Student : Person {
    Approve _approve = new Approve();
    public Approve Approve {
        get { return _approve; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

It's a good case, IMHO, to use interfaces here, something like that:

```
  // Interfaces:

  // General person
  public interface IPerson {
    int Id { get; set; }
    string FirstName { get; set; }
    string LastName { get; set; }
    string Type { get; set; }
  }

  // Approvable person
  public interface IApprovable {
    bool Approved { get; set; }
    DateTime ApprovedDate { get; set; }
    int ApprovedUserId { get; set; }
  } 

  // Student is a IPerson + IApprovable
  public interface IStudent: IPerson, IApprovable {
    DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    DateTime EnrollmentDate { get; set; }
  }

  // So classes will be

  public class Approve: IApprovable {
    ... //TODO: Implement IApprovable interface here
  } 

  public class Faculty: IPerson, IApprovable {
    public DateTime HiredDate { get; set; }

    ... //TODO: Implement IPerson interface here
    ... //TODO: Implement IApprovable interface here
  }

  public class Student: IStudent {
    public string Remarks { get; set; }

    ... //TODO: Implement IStudent interface here
  }
```

Answer (score 6):

**Short Answer**

Consider using interfaces instead, which allow for multiple inheritance and can be declared using the `interface` keyword.

**Long Answer**

Inheritance from multiple base classes in C# is illegal. Classes may only have 1 base class while they can implement any number of interfaces. There are [several reasons for this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/07/why-doesn-t-c-support-multiple-inheritance.aspx) but it mostly comes down to that multiple inheritance introduces much more complexity into a class hierarchy.

Interfaces are used to declare a group of common functionality (methods and properties) that must be implemented by class.

To modify your existing code to use interfaces (instead of multiple inheritance), you can do the following:

```
public interface IApprove // Defines a set of functionality that a class must implement.
{
    // All these properties must be inherited as public when implemented.
    bool Approved { get; set; } // Property declaration.
    DateTime ApprovedDate { get; set; }
    int ApprovedUserId { get; set; }
}

public class Student : Person, IApprove
{
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public DateTime EnrollmentDate { get; set; }
    public string Remarks { get; set; }

    #region IApprove Implementation

    private bool _approved; // Private variable that is accessed through the 'Approved' property of the 'IApprove' interface.
    public bool Approved // Defines 'Approved' inherited from IApprove
    {
        get { return _approved; }
        set { _approved = value; }
    }

    private DateTime _approvedDate;
    public DateTime ApprovedDate // Defines 'ApprovedDate' inherited from IApprove.
    {
        get { return _approvedDate; }
        set { _approvedDate = value; }
    }

    private int _approvedUserId;
    public int IApprove.ApprovedUserId // Alternative syntax to define an interfaces property.
    {
        get { return _approvedUserId; }
        set { _approvedUserId = value; }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

This approach abstracts the implementation of an *IApprove* interface and, like multiple inheritance, allows the user to operate on objects that implement *IApprove* yet their concrete type is unknown (or irrelevant).

For more information on the usage of interfaces in C# refer to:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87d83y5b.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Consider the following example , it uses two interfaces :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


////////
////////
/// Multiple Inheritance With Interfaces

public interface Interface1
{
    void func1();
    void fun();
}

public interface Interface2
{
    void func2();
    void fun();
}

public class MyTestBaseClass : Interface1, Interface2
{
    void Interface1.func1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("From MyInterface1 Function()");
        return;
    }


    void Interface2.func2()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("From MyInterface2 Function()");
        return;
    }

    void Interface1.fun()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("fun1()");
    }

    void Interface2.fun()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("fun2()");
    }


    public static void Main()
    {
        MyTestBaseClass myclass = new MyTestBaseClass();
        ((Interface1)myclass).func1();
        ((Interface2)myclass).func2();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Composite pattern

```
    public class Student:Person
    {
        public Approve App { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
        public DateTime EnrollmentDate { get; set; }
        public string Remarks { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Some basic example using the **Decorator** design pattern:

```
public class Class1
{
    public void Method1()
    {
        Console.write($"Class1: Method1, MyInt: {MyInt}");
    }

    public int MyInt { get; set; }
}

public class Class2
{
    public void Method2()
    {   
        Console.write($"Class2: Method2, MyInt: {MyInt}");      
    }

    public int MyInt { get; set; }
 }

public class MultipleClass
{
    private Class1 class1 = new Class1();
    private Class2 class2 = new Class2();

    public void Method1()
    {
        class1.Method1();
    }
    public void Method2()
    {
        class2.Method2();
    }

    private int _myInt;
    public int MyInt
    {
        get { return this._myInt; }
        set
        {
            this._myInt = value;
            class1.MyInt = value;
            class2.MyInt = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Demo:

```
 MultipleClass multipleClass = new MultipleClass();
 multipleClass.Method1(); //OUTPUT: Class1: Method1, MyInt: 1 
 multipleClass.Method2(); //OUTPUT: Class2: Method2, MyInt: 1
 multipleClass.MyInt = 1;
```