# Can I restrict the accessibility of a class to just another class?

Tags: c#, class

For example if I have `Class1` and `Class2` but I only want `Class3` to have access to them, how would I go about setting this up?

I was looking into multiple inheritance, but it doesn't seem like it's possible in C#. I would like for my presentation layer to only call `Class3` and `Class3` will either call `Class1` or `Class2` based on a property set in the constructor of `Class3`.

```
Class1()
{
  object GetData()
  {
  }
}

Class2()
{
  object GetData()
  {
  }
}

public Class3()
{
   bool mForClass2 = false;
   Class1 mClass1;
   Class2 mClass2;
   public Class3(bool forClass2)
   {
      mForClass2 = forClass2;
      mClass1 = New Class1();
      mClass2 = New Class2();
   }

   public object getdata()
   {
       if(mForClass2)
       {
         return mClass2.getdata();
       }
       else
       {
          return mClass1.getdata();
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a job for an Interface.  Your forClass2 bool doesn't make a ton of sense.  Can you provide more information on what you are trying to do?  What context?

Comment: i agree with LarsTech, i found this, and i think it will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18438196/c-sharp-multiple-inheritance

Comment: ... this is exactly what inner classes are for.

Comment: pretty much my boss wants to have a set up where we have a base class for a circuit and this class will take a enum when initiated of either order or inventory. the base class will then determine to add,update, or get data from inventory or from order(class1 and class2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is exactly what private inner classes are designed to do.

```
public class Class3
{
    public enum Type { Order, Inventory }
    private interface IProvidesGetData{ object getData(); }
    private class Class1 : IProvidesGetData { /* ... */ }
    private class Class2 : IProvidesGetData { /* ... */ }

    //...
}
```

Comment: this sounds like the solution i need, just didn't want to cram all that code in 1 file but it works. thanks for the help.

Comment: @user2493906 it does not need to be one file, declare `Class3` as `public partial class Class3` and you can have multiple files all have data for `Class3` they all just need to be inside the same assembly. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22821426/80274) for a example

Comment: @clcto is that VB instead of C#? also `ProvidesGetData` really should be `IProvidesGetdata`.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain as you can see by me using `implements`, I thought this was a java question, updated.

Answer (score 1):

To extend off of what [clcto answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22820969/80274), you don't need to all be in a single file. You can split it up by using [partial classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488.aspx)

```
//In Class3.cs
public partial class Class3
{
    public enum Type { Order, Inventory }
    //...
}

//In IProvidedsGetData.cs
partial class Class3
{
    private interface IProvidesGetData
    {
        object getData(); 
    }
}

//In Class1.cs
partial class Class3
{
    private class Class1 : IProvidesGetData 
    {
        /* ... */ 
    }
}

//in Class2.cs
partial class Class3
{
    private class Class2 : IProvidesGetData 
    {
        /* ... */ 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make both `Class1` and `Class2` `internal` and put them together with `public Class3` in the same package.

This will restrict visibility of the first two to that package (essentially: `Class3`) and `class3` is still publicly available.

Ofcourse, don't add any `[InternalsVisibleTo]` stuff.

As others have noted you can also use several different `private` classes, but that will give you one big source file: not handy to work with. Using this method you can split it up over multiple files.

Following your comment, you could have a setup like this:

```
public enum CrudAction {
    Add, Update, Get
}

public class UIController { 
    public void Perform(CrudAction action) {
        switch(action){
            case CrudAction.Add: new AddAction().Perform(); break;
            case CrudAction.Get: new GetAction().Perform(); break;
            case CrudAction.Update: new UpdateAction().Perform(); break;
            default: throw new ArgumentException();
        }
    }
}

internal interface IAction {
    void Perform();
}

internal class AddAction : IAction { }
internal class GetAction : IAction { }
internal class UpdateAction : IAction { }
```

Now everything is split over multiple files and you can only access it using

```
new UIController().Perform(CrudAction.Update);
```